# Concatenate JSONB accessors in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(students::jsonb -> 'users') as e
   where e @> '{"id": "1"}'
```

However I would like to change this:

```
students::jsonb -> 'users'
```

to not be hard coded but take an array of nodes (for example ["class", "users"]) and concatenate them to create this

```
students::jsonb -> 'class' -> 'users'
```

I need this query to be dynamic because I will not always have the data that I am looking for in the same nodes.

Comment: Why the `::jsonb` cast? If you are storing json values, your column should be defined as `jsonb`.

Comment: it's just a workaround that I have to do until we make that column be of type jsonb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you are looking for the `#>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
students #> '{class,users}'
```